# Using rsync to mirror the contents of a directory on a NAS

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, synology-diskstation

I have two network attached storages (NAS). I am trying to mirror a directory on `nasA` (IP ending .69) to `nasB` (IP ending .11) using a Windows Subsystem for Linux.

On my laptop I SSH to nasA and try this ...

`rsync -a /volume1/test me@x.x.x.x:/volume1/test`

but I get following error message:

```
Current status: 255 (Interrupted)
Standard output/error:
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(254) [sender=3.1.2]
```

If I try to SSH to nasA (still on my windows laptop)

```
rsync -a me@x.x.x.69:/volume1/movies/prerolls me@x.x.x.11:/volume1/movies/prerolls
```

I get

```
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks
P

Comment: Welcome (out) on SuperUser. Please [edit] to make the situation a little more clear. For what I understand you are executing the command from a WSL shell on a computer with Windows and two NAS are attached.  You have an `Host key verification failed` error. Is `/volume1/test` accessible?  Did you try something like `rsync -a me@nasA:/volume1/test me@nasB:/volume1/test` ? Can you access to both NAS? If you set the ssh keys remember that they should be valid for user/password/host so the host from which the command comes is also important. Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Hastur. I will edit the OP now. " Is /volume1/test accessible?" I can see in in File Explorer on my Windows laptop but when I connect via ssh i can "cd" to volume1 but I cannot see "test". Thanks

Comment: I've picked another accessible dir and tried "rsync -a me@x.x.x.69:/volume1/movies/prerolls me@x.x.x.11:/volume1/movies/prerolls" but get "The source and destination cannot both be remote."

Comment: Ok I see... This may be [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183516/66388). A second is to connect to a shell on the NAS (if this is possible) and from there do the `rsync`. Another is to mount the nasA directory on your subsystem, then it will result to be a normal --but slower-- directory from which you can copy or rsync as you desire...

Comment: It sounds like nasA is not configured to be ready as a ssh client? Make sure you can ssh fron nasA to nasB first?

Comment: Btw an *offtopic* note: when you want to "mirror" with rsync, you most likely want to include a trailing slash in the source path, or, omit the last component of the source path in the destination path. For example, `rsync -a /volume1/test/ me@x.x.x.x:/volume1/test/` or `rsync -a /volume1/test me@x.x.x.x:/volume1/` (the trailing slashes in the destination paths are optional, but well, semantics).

Comment: On nasA please try `ssh me@x.x.x.11` (i.e. connect from nasA to nasB). Report the attempt and full error message in your question